# Changing values to arrays result in NAN

Tags: python, list, integration

I am starting to learn Python and have witnessed a weird problem for which I wasn't able to find relevant info online.

since I can't post the actual code, i will be using dummy code.

```
def model(x):
    A = list of length 4  
    B = list of length 4  
    C = list of length 4  
    D = list of length 4  

    # below methods of calculating X, one of which works
    # Method 1: WORKS
    X0 = A[0] + B[0] + C[0] + D[0]  
    X1 = A[1] + B[1] + C[1] + D[1]  
    X2 = A[2] + B[2] + C[2] + D[2]  
    X3 = A[3] + B[3] + C[3] + D[3]
    X = [X0, X1, X2, X3]

    # Method 2: DOES NOT WORK, 
    X = [A[i] + B[i] + C[i] + D[i] for i in range(4)]

    M = list of shape 4x4
    result = numpy.matmul(M, X)
    # result = [nan, nan, nan, nan] after some iterations

    return result
```

Above model returns a `dy/dt` matrix that i use in the below code to integrate

```
h   = 0.1;                              # timestep
sim_time = np.arange(0, 1500, h)        # timeseries
data = []
for i in sim_time:
    xdot    = model(x);                     
    x       = [a + h * b for a,b in zip(x, xdot)] 
    data.append(x)
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I did find out that this could be due to floating point error but not sure if this is the case or how to overcome this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the result for some iterations before it turns to nan

```
[-0.0383724   0.32659622 -0.02615451  0.01465148]
[-0.04153605  0.43814228 -0.02797397 -0.19174319]
[-0.04523129  0.07295898 -0.02615787  0.48396945]
[-0.0502085   0.88057674 -0.03373012 -0.90358412]
[-0.07082689 -0.20715555  0.00221235  1.75009264]
[-0.06635629  1.67610358 -0.04464798 -2.09508071]
[-0.0996444  -0.47602223  0.01246201  2.41644675]
[  -32.63095619   564.81941652   -14.72529351 -1025.05888268]
[-4.51778757e+09 -8.04785367e+10  2.09936804e+09  1.42336386e+11]
[-1.54489920e+31  2.75142984e+32 -7.17739692e+30 -4.86623834e+32]
[-3.08719207e+90 -5.49821772e+91  1.43426848e+90  9.72426681e+91]
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:323: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  state_derivative =[X[0]*(U**2/L), X[1]*(U**2/L), X[2]*(U**2/L**2), X[3]*(U**2/L**2)]
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:205: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  u         =x[4]/U
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:206: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  v         =x[5]/U
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:207: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  p         =x[7]*L/U
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:208: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  r         =x[6]*L/U
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:233: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  u = (x[4] - uc)/U;
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:234: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  v = (x[5] - vc)/U;
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:265: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  n_c=n_c*U/L;
C:\Users\Mod_18122018.py:266: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  n=n*U/L;
[nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan]
```

Comment: what is the output of `print(X)`??? why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: by the way, you are doing `model(x)` (calling `model` with a parameter), but the function is defined without formal parameters. Should I assume this is due to the simplification?

Comment: Sorry, its just a type error in the question. should be `def model(x):`. As mentioned in the post, the output of x is the expected result when using method 1 but when using method 2 the results change to nan after several iterations.

Comment: What is the argument `x` being used for in `model(x)`? It's not referenced anywhere in the function.  Since you are creating dummy code you should be creating a [MCVE] so that the issue can be reproduced.  At this point it's unclear what the input/output are and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Since you're already using numpy in your code, why don't you use `numpy.array([A, B, C, D]).sum(axis=1)` to obtain your `X`?

Comment: Also, not sure which kind of differential equation you're trying to integrate, but maybe your problem is not floating point precision but numerical convergence. Does your integration step fulfill the CFL condition?

Comment: @Idlehands, I use an array of initial values [0, 0, 0, 0] as input to the model. The model provides the `dy/dt` to which I use the Euler integration scheme. I am sorry if the error is not reproducible. I have a complete working code that utilizes method 1 for the calculation. I am only trying to make it in simpler steps by using method 2 that does not work.

Comment: @N.P., thanks for the suggestion. I tried it (using axis =0 would be the correct way) but still getting nan output. Not sure if the output here will help. I will add it to the post.